# Singleline - TextBox does not scroll in text input to the end

Tags: c#, wpf

Unfortunately my Single Line `Textbox` does not scroll to the end on text input.

I deleted all styles and used an empty `Textbox`.

[image]

If I start an empty `Project`, it works as normal

[image]

Does anyone know which is the problem?

Edit: It's just a empty textbox
`<TextBox></TextBox>`
and works nowhere in my project

Edit:

```
<Grid Width="250" Background="{StaticResource SolidColorBrushText}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--  name  -->
            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Content="Name"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" /> 
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Images are not loading. Please update

Comment: Please if it's not a long text add directly here your code

Comment: And please use the built in function to attach images. External services may shutdown and the images are lost.

Comment: its only a empty textbox     <TextBox ></TextBox> on both examples i tried it on different places in my project -> it works nowhere

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of the XAML, including the TextBox's parent elements.

Comment: Edited, unfortunately i cant update again with images cause i need 10 more posts :-(  its my second question here

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the text box container(possibly StackPanel) is expanding and giving space to ever expanding text box.

Try to limit the containers width then it should work as expected.

Comment: Its a Grid but it still don't work with a limited width

Comment: The edit you made is not all of it. There are explicit style defined on label and on grid. I bet there are also some implicit styles defined in App.xaml. PLease share all relevant details otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I just deleted all styles now

Comment: You still have some kind of style being inherited somewhere. What about you App.xaml. The fact that when you start a new project everything works correctly tells me that some kind of style definition in this project is redefining the behavior.

Comment: there are so much styles definied in the app. Its a big tool, i just deleted all styles wich belongs to this case  (Grid / label / textbox)  i use it this in a usercontrol wich is used as a dialog (like a message box). So as normal no style from the app should disturb?